# How to add .exe file into nuget package

Tags: nuget

There is an .exe file I would like to add my nuget package but I can't seem to find the proper way of doing it..

I would like to add the .exe file into the bin\Debug and bin\Release folders..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyApi</id>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <title>MyApi</title>
    <authors>ASIM GUNDUZ</authors>
    <owners>ASIM GUNDUZ</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <license type="expression">MIT</license>
    <description>.Net api</description>
    <releaseNotes>Hello World</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <tags>AApi</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>

    <file src ="bin\Release\MyApi.dll"  target="lib"/>

    <file src ="Sample_Usage.cs"  target="content\AApi\Sample_Usage.cs"/>
  </files>

</package>
```

Comment: How are you creating the package?

Comment: I've updated my question, This creates the package and place the sample_usage.cs into the folder but I would like to add chromedriver.exe into bin\debug and release folders

Comment: You need to [include a MSBuild targets file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package) in your package, have a target run `afterTargets="build"` and copy the file to the appropriate directory.